# How to make use of Chrome's Password Suggester as a Developer

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, autofill

I want to make use of Chrome's Password Suggester but it doesn't work when I want to confirm the password entered. It auto fills the first Password field but doesn't populate second confirmation password field.

Tried autocomplete="new-password"/"current-password"/"password".